# trim output in powershell or cut a specific amount of letters

Tags: powershell

in many scripts i have the problem, that it always shows me the complete name like domain\user.
for example like that

```
Invoke-command -computer computername {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI -Name LastLoggedOnUser | select -ExpandProperty LastLoggedOnUser}
```

how can i cut off the domain and just have the user name?
i have tried that for example.

```
Invoke-command -computer computername{Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI -Name LastLoggedOnUser | select -ExpandProperty LastLoggedOnUser @{N="LastLoggedOnUser";E={$_.LastLoggedOnUser -replace ".+\"}}}
```

Comment: the simplest would seem to be just using `.Split('\')[-1]` on the string. [*grin*]

Comment: where would I put that in?

Comment: In your expression

Comment: @chkdsk  - please take a look at my Answer for details. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with :

```
Invoke-command -computer computername {Get-ItemProperty `
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI `
-Name LastLoggedOnUser | select -ExpandProperty LastLoggedOnUser} | `
%{ $_ -replace "^[^\\]*\\","" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is a special regex character that would need to be escaped to be taken literally.

```
'stackoverflow\joe' -replace '.*\\'

joe
```

Answer (score 0):

here is yet another way to get the no-domain-name last logged on user from that registry key [*grin*] ...

what it does ...

- sets the reg key to use
- sets the prop of that key to get the value from
- grabs that value
- splits on the `\`
- takes the last item from that split result
- assigns it to a $Var
- displays the value therein

the code ...

```
$LogonUiRegKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI'
$TargetPropName = 'LastLoggedOnUser'
$LastLoggedOnUser = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $RegKey -Name $TargetPropName).Split('\')[-1]

$LastLoggedOnUser
```

output = `MyUserName`